Is "arriving " a gerund?

All day there were ladies and gentlemen arriving at the Red House.

is "arriving " a gerund?

Straight verb, like "He was napping at the house."

A gerund is when a -ing verb is used as a noun, as in "Eating is necessary to live". What makes you think this is acting noun-like?

There is a spectrum of usage with participles ranging through adverbial 'they came vaunting, rather than ashamed ; adjectival 'her racing heart' ; and nounal 'their feastings were gluttonous'. Sometimes there is both a noun flavour and a verbal flavour present. which is what makes participles actively powerful and yet descriptive all at the same time. Energetic, they.

I would identify this as present progressive case, which consists of a form of  "to be" + "-ing". What makes "arriving" look like a gerund in this context is that "arriving" has been separated from "were", and the sentence has "there" as a placeholder subject. The true subject is "ladies and gentlemen," i. e. "All day ladies and gentlemen were arriving at the Red House."

In other words, "arriving" is here a present participle, used with "be" to form the progressive aspect.


All day there were [ladies and gentlemen] arriving at the Red House.

No: traditional grammar calls "arriving" a present participle.
Note that this is an existential clause, where the subordinate participial clause, "arriving at the Red House", is an extension, not part of the displaced subject NP (bracketed).
